# GPU Mining Speed

Tags: hash, hashpower, gpu-mining, gpu

I am a bit new to the whole mining thing and just have a economical issue when it comes to selecting GPUs. Sorry if the title is in appropriate.

Let's just say in mining Ethereum,
a 1070 ti (costs $945) has a speed of Approx 30-31 Mhz
a 1080 ti (costs $1450) has a speed of approx 38 mhz
a 1060 3gb (costs $350 used) has a speed of approx 20 mhz.

Putting aside the brand new/used factor, PCI slot usage on the board, DAG size etc and considering only sheer economics/speed,

I could buy about 3 1060s and get a total speed of approx 60 mhz rather than buy a 1070 ti.
I could buy about 4 1060s a get a total speed of approx 80 mhz.

Therefore, does buying 3/4 1060s rather than 1 1080ti or 1070ti get me at an advantage in solving shares?

Does the speed/ram in a GPU has a part in playing the share solving scenario? What would you recommend if I am at a budget in starting up this mining thingi?

I know individually the 1080ti will out perform the 1060s in it's sleep.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I see you have experience with other SE sites so I will leave the explanations. Please enjoy your time over here at Bitcoin.SE.

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially answered your own question. Mining comes down to sheer hashing power and 80MHz > 38MHz. You just need appropriately configured mining software.

If you have the choice, always buy graphics cards with higher clock speeds for GPU and RAM - provided you consider the need to cool them.

Comment: Hi, I was under the impression that 1 GPU was meant to process 1 share/task. If I have 6 GPUs 6 shares would be tried solved. Was I wrong? Do all GPU's combined together solve a share? I just use EWBF, Claymore, Cgminer or a miner recommended by a pool and point my wallet address and update the pools address/ports. Do I need to do something else, as suggested by you of "configuring mining software"?

Comment: It is totally dependant on the mining software you are using. Either more shares on one worker (workers is for pooled mining) or more workers. Either way same hash power. Work out the capabilities of the mining software you are using first. Even if the mining software cannot handle more than one GPU, can you run more than one instance of the mining software? Look for setup guides for the mining software you are going to be using.